# C++ make function return array cross file

Tags: c++, arrays, file, pointers

I'm looking to make a function return an array of set size, and assign the value of that array to another array. The function is located in one file and the array I will be assigning it's return value to is located in another.

I'm attempting to do this in an SFML project. Whenever I call the array function, my program freezes and stops responding.

generate_maze.cpp:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "generate_maze.h"

char* generate_maze() {

    char test_maze[169] = {
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };

    return test_maze;

}
```

extract of main.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "controls.h"
#include "generate_maze.h"

...

char* maze = generate_maze();
std::cout << (int) maze[0] << std::endl;
```

generate_maze.h:

```
char* generate_maze();
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: you are looking for `std::array`

Comment: Your `generate_maze` function is returning a pointer to a variable allocated on the stack, `test_maze`. This is undefined behaviour, as the lifetime of `test_maze` is only as long as the function enclosing its definition. Several solutions: allocate it on the heap, make it static, make it global, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`generate_maze` returns the address of `test_maze[0]`, which is a local variable. You should never ever return addresses of (or references to) local variables from a function.

Allocate the maze on the heap instead and return that:

```
char* generate_maze() {
    char local[] = {
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };
    char* ret = new char[sizeof local];

    memcpy(ret, local, sizeof local);

    return ret;
}
```

Alternatively, just return a `std::vector` which does its own memory management.

```
std::vector<char> generate_maze() {
    return {0, 0, 0, ...};
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code does not work because `generate_maze()` returns a pointer to a local variable, which is destroyed on exiting the function. To make it work one *could* design `generate_maze()` to allocate an array of `char` via `new`, then the allocated array survives after `generate_maze()` is finished. But that would also require to explicitly free the memory, after `char *maze` is no longer used.

A much better *c++-like* solution is the following.
If the size of the array is fixed, you should better use `std::array` to store the result of `generate_maze()`, as:

```
#include <array> 

std::array<char, 169> generate_maze() {

    return { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };
}
```

If the size of the array returned by `generate_maze()` is not fixed, the correct way is to use `std::vector` and declare `generate_maze()` as

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<char> generate_maze();
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`generate_maze()` returns pointer to local array, which is destroyed when function exits. 
To solve this problem, you can define test_maze static: `static char test_maze[]`.  
This will create one permanent array for all `generaze_maze()` function calls. If you going to implement `generate_maze()` to return different maze arrays, better use `std::vector` or `std::array`.